# Data on Screen does not update when updating from other thread in Iphone

Tags: iphone, threadpool

I have a weired problem and i want some good solution.

Problem is that i have a method in my ViewController i.e.

```
 -(void)updateMyInformation;
```

I also have one Seperate non-UIThread running in my application. Other than the Main Thread.
Now that thread after every 10 minutes calls my updateMyInformation method of my ViewController.

it calls it successfully. I am using NSNotification for that. but the problem is that its updating the information in my variables but does not update it on the view.

What can be the problem. can anybody help

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the UI on the main thread:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateMyInformation) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:false];
```

Comment: where do i write this method? in the seperate non-UI thread class ??